# PHP line break inside of cell remove qoute

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

This is my PHP

```
$val = "";
foreach($data as $v){
  $val .= '"' . $v . "\n" . '"';
}
```

The result is

```
//this is inside of cell
sample
"sample
"sample
```

This is correct but I cant figure out how to remove the double quote in `"sample`. Only the first value dont have a double quote the rest will have a double quote.

EDIT

This is the result of my code

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but you probably intended to do this: `$val .= '"' . $v . '"' . "\n";`

Comment: You want the first `sample` without quotes and the following two `sample` with quotes?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `$val .= '"' . $v . '"' . "\n";` this will line break in cell what I want is line break only inside of single cell.

Comment: @kerbholz I want to remove also the quotes on the next `sample` like the first `sample`

Comment: So you want NO quotes at all? Go with `S N Tiwari`'s answer then

Comment: You could try `$val = implode("\n", $data);` instead

Comment: ^ maybe, `$val = "\"" . implode("\n", $data) , "\"";`

Comment: @splash58 so I dont need to foreach sir?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization yes, sure

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove some part of your code, you will get solution:

```
$val = "";
foreach($data as $v){
  $val .= $v . "\n";
}
```

Just try (Maintaining line break in excel):

```
    $val = "";
   foreach($data as $v){
          $val .= $v . "<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />";
        }
```

Comment: hope this will help !

Comment: Yes but it doesnt line break inside of cell instead the next value will go to next cell

Comment: Replace `"\n"` with  `"\r\n"` and check. @PureRhymerOrganization

Comment: still going to next cell

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this should do the trick

```
$i = 0
foreach($data as $v){
  $val .= '"' . $v . "\n" . (count($data) !== $i) ? '"' : '';
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the php function `trim` like this:

```
$val = "";
foreach($data as $v){
  if( ''==$val) {
      $val .= trim('"' . $v . "\n" . '"','"');
  }else{
      $val .= '"' . $v . "\n" . '"','"';
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt line break inside of cell instead the next value will go to next cell

Answer (score 0):

```
 $val .= '"' . $v . "</br>" . '"';
$val=str_replace('"','',$val);
```

I think this is what you are looking for inside  your loop. It will remove every double quote.

Comment: it doesnt line break inside of cell instead the next value will go to next cell

Answer (score 0):

**Well there you go :**

```
$data = ['sample','sample','sample'];
$val = "";
foreach($data as $v){
  $val .= $v . "\n" ;
}
```

**Then you simply use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) like this :**

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, [$val]);
```

**And you get the result you want :**

[image]

Comment: It will not line break inside of cell.

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization How do you create your csv file ? With fputcsv() ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is

```
$val = "";
foreach($data as $v){
  $val .= $v . "\n";
}

 $val = '"'. $val .'"';
```

I need to add the `'"'` outside of the loop.